# Passing two php variables to another page from a link

Tags: php

Ok so I'm building a simple question/answer site and this is a loop that outputs all the questions asked previously in link form.  I'm trying to concat two variables to the next page url so I can get them and work with them there but it will only allow one?  I've tried everything but not working?  See the only comment section of my code for the crux of the issue.  Thank you.

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "dylan326";
$password = "";
$dbname = "questions87";
$port = 3306;


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 
$port);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "<a href='index.html'> Log out </a><br>
<a href='ask.php'> Ask a question</a><br>
<br />
<br />";

echo "Answer another users question: <br><br />";

$sql = "SELECT q_id,question, username FROM questions";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$q_id = $row['q_id'];
$question = $row['question'];
$username = $row['username'];

//right here I need to add(concat) the second variable $username 
//I need to get both on the next page url but not allowing me to 

echo ('<a href="totalqs.php?q_id=' . $q_id .'   " >' . $question . 
'</a>'  . '<br>');
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: `example.php?one=value&second=value`.

Comment: Be carefull with `SQL Injection` btw. There is no danger in this particular script, but the way you set it up seems you might be open for it. Use `prepared statements`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming that `$username` has a value):

```
echo ('<a href="totalqs.php?q_id=' . $q_id .'   " >' . $question . " Username:" . $username . '</a>'  . '<br>');
```

Comment: I tested this with;

Comment: $q_id = $_GET['q_id'];
$username = $_GET[username];


echo $q_id;
echo $username;

Comment: and I'm still only getting ID

Comment: What happens if you echo $username alone?

Comment: Ahh this worked.  Other people answered the same but I'll give it to you because I was trying this without values for username first and it was not working but now it makes sense.  Thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Get requests can pass multiple variables for example: `{host}?var1=val1&var2=val2&var2=val3`

You could echo out a link with a get request in it:

```
echo ('<a href="totalqs.php?q_id=' . $q_id .'&username='. $username .'" >' . $question .'</a>'  . '<br>');
```

And then, you could use `$_GET` to retrieve these vars in `totalqs.php`. Like:

```
$_GET['username']
```

would give you the value of the username.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing HTTP GET so instead of trying to concat 2 strings, why not just have something like

```
totalqs.php?q_id=$q_id&question=$question&username=$username
```

Then in the totalqs.php, you'll do something like

```
$q_id = $_GET['q_id'];
$question = $_GET['question'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

This is assuming you have access to totalqs.php.

Comment: I don't think he wants 3 variables passed, just 2. It shows how to do it, which is good. But he doesn't want the question to be passed to the next page.

Comment: yea just two but I think I understand what you're saying and I will work on this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can send to variables by adding the `&` and then continuing to add values.

**Example**

```
example.php?one=value&second=value
```

**In your case**

```
totalqs.php?q_id=$q_id&username=$username
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your echo statement. This concatenates your second value `$username` with name `user`:

```
echo '<a href="totalqs.php?q_id='.$q_id.'&user='.$username.'">'.$question.'</a><br />';
```

Note that you do not need parentheses in your echo statement. You need to properly concatenate your string (you need to learn more about concatenation). In the next page, you can access `q_id` and `user` as

```
$id = $_GET['q_id'];
$username = $_GET['user'];
```

Comment: Yea I'm still just getting the ID on the next page but thanks for the help.

Comment: What does your link look like when you click the corrected link here? Your username variable seems to be empty.